# unable to display the image in the web page

Tags: javascript

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>

 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
 <div >
 <img border="0" src="img/header.gif" alt="Pulpit rock" width="904" height="128">



             <script type="text/javascript">
              function detectBrowser() {
                     // document.write("<a href="jre.html"><img src="C:\Documents and Settings\nawab.a\Desktop\header.gif" border="0"></a>");
                     //document.write("<br/>");
                    // document.write("<a href='jre.html','width=100' title='KNOW Your JRE VERSION'>JRE Version</a>");

                     //<a href="../html-link.htm" target="popup" onclick="window.open('../html-link.htm','name','width=600,height=400')">Open page in new window</a>
                     document.write("<br/>");
                     document.write("<br/>");

                     var N = navigator.appName;
                     var UA = navigator.userAgent;
                     var temp;
                     var browserVersion = UA.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
                     if (browserVersion && (temp = UA.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i)) != null)
                         browserVersion[2] = temp[1];
                     browserVersion = browserVersion ? [browserVersion[1], browserVersion[2]] : [N, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];

                     document.write("<b>Browser & ContentVerse Software Property</b>")
                     document.write("<br>");

                     document.write("Browser Name & Version:  " + browserVersion);
                     document.write("<br>");

                     document.write("<br>");





                    // readValue(); // function for get dll details......

                 }
      </script>
      </div>
      <body onload="javascript:detectBrowser();">
      </BODY>

      </HTML>
```

Hi, this code is working fine but unable to display the image.... 
i want to display the image at the head and then all the information
i think the problem is because of body onload function..

i also tried o display the image in the hyperlink but not working.

Comment: is this correct html syntex?

Answer (score 0):

Do you run this offline (i mean on your computer) or online, on a web server ?

Just asking because `C:\Documents and Settings\nawab.a\Desktop\header.gif` is a local path of your computer, not accessible from a remote web server. If this is the case, upload the image on your server and change this path.